# InetLoad::load throws connection error nsis

Tags: installation, nsis

I was trying to download a file using

```
InetLoad::load "https://www.dropbox.com/xxx/xxx.exe" "$INSTDIR\temp\xxx.exe"
```

But this is giving me connection error. Any idea how to overcome connection error.

I have tried inetc::get also but no use. I am guessing its the same issue with inetc plugin also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INetC uses WinInet, the same internet library as Internet Explorer. Could it be a network problem on your end? It works fine for me:

```
Section
InitPluginsDir
inetc::get "https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxx/yyyy.exe?dl=1" "$PluginsDir\vcredist_x86.exe" /END
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0
SectionEnd
```

Have you tried to inspect the network traffic with WireShark or Fiddler?

Comment: I was using "https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxx/yyyy.exe?dl=0". As soon as I changed dl=1 at tend of the url everything seems to be working fine. I could not get **IntelLoad::load** to work but **inetc::get** works just fine.

Comment: There is no such thing as IntelLoad, it is called InetLoad and has been replaced by INetC...

Comment: My bad I edited the original post. Thank you for correcting. One thing with INetC::get; If I try to download from ftp location it does not show the correct file size. All it shows is **_312kb(0%) of 0kb @1414kb/s_**. Is there any issue with INetC while downloading from ftp?